# How to use SBPL for Benchmarking?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-groovy, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I already executed some succesfull benchmark-runs with ompl planners. (ROS GROOVY)
Now I want to repeat the same with the sbpl_arm planner.

My SBPL-benchmark server .launch file:

```
<launch>

  <node name="moveit_benchmark_server" pkg="moveit_ros_benchmarks" type="moveit_run_benchmark" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find TX60L_Final11)/config/kinematics.yaml"/>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find TX60L_Final11)/config/sbpl_planning.yaml"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

my guessed sbpl_planning.yaml-file (I orientaded at the ompl_planning.yaml-file)

```
planner_configs:
  AraConfigDefault:
    type: geometric::Ara
  
arm:
  planner_configs:
    - ArakConfigDefault
 
dummy:
  planner_configs:
    - ArakConfigDefault
```

**edit:**
when I start my .launch-file Terminal shows following:

```
...
[ INFO] [1366667891.580784849]: Attempting to load and configure ompl_interface_ros/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1366667891.690143180]: Not displaying OMPL exploration data structures.
[ INFO] [1366667891.691618019]: Initializing OMPL interface using ROS parameters
[ERROR] [1366667891.696771314]: Could not find the planner configuration 'ArakConfigDefault' on the param server
[ERROR] [1366667891.699387276]: Could not find the planner configuration 'ArakConfigDefault' on the param server
[ INFO] [1366667891.703239199]: Available planner instances: ompl_interface_ros/OMPLPlanner
```

Why is the benchmark_server assuming that I use OMPL?
How can I fix it?

**Edit:** Here is a [paper](http://ioan.sucan.ro/files/pubs/benchmarks_iros2012.pdf), where sbpl - benmarking is realized in MoveIt!

**Edit:** Here are my [MoveIt! configuration files](http://www.file-upload.net/download-7509986/TX60L_Final11.zip.html). And my [6Dof_robot](http://www.file-upload.net/download-7509998/learning_urdf.zip.html).

Many Thanks in advance
viovio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60821/how-to-use-sbpl-for-benchmarking?/) by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2013-04-23**:
Groovy was not released at the time that the paper was written. The original version of the sbpl_arm_planner was used to generate those stats in Fuerte. It seems like you are using Gil Jones' version of sbpl_planners so anyone familiar with his implementation would be better suited to answer this.

**Comment by [rosrookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3050/rosrookie/) on 2013-04-23**:
At the moment I don't use any sbpl planners, I only read about it. I'm a little bit confused: In this paper sbpl was used with MoveIt! (end of page 1) for benchmarks, but at this time Groovy was not released. So it had to run under Fuerte, where I thought Moveit won't run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two implementations of the SBPL environments for arm planning.

1. There is the original sbpl_arm_planner package that does not yet support Groovy so it can't be used yet with the benchmarking software. It's being upgraded and a robot-agnostic version will be made available by the end of June.
2. The sbpl_planners package that was written by a developer that is no longer at WG (Gil Jones). I'm not sure whether it's still being maintained or not. I don't know the status of this one.

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-04-23**:
Thanks Ben, for your answer. I updated my post with a link (http://ioan.sucan.ro/files/pubs/benchmarks_iros2012.pdf) to a paper, where it was realized with MoveIt!. The MoveIt! API (http://moveit.ros.org/doxygen/files.html) shows that sbpl is included in MoveIt Or did we talked at cross purposes?

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2013-04-23**:
The SBPL is a library of graph search algorithms. It also contains simple implementations of environments in which those planners can be used on. The environments that the package contains are strictly for simpler domains such as 2D & 3D nav. More complex environments (arm) are packaged separately.

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2013-04-23**:
Actually, it looks like the other implementation of arm planning with the SBPL (#2 from above) is in fact packaged with Moveit. So someone must be maintaining it. I can't offer any help with that implementation though because I've never used it.

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-04-24**:
Thx for your afforts. I contacted Dave Coleman. So hopefully he can help.